# iOS 7 - Navigation Bar - Background Mode

Tags: colors, background, ios7, navigationbar

I'm having a weird behaviour when i put my application in background.

The navigation bar should be green, but sometimes it appears black but only when in background.

Any suggestion to fix this behaviour?

Screenshot here: http://d.pr/i/wgfd